# Sending automated email using company email address

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, smtp

I have a method that basically automates the sending of an email to our company distribution list, with my company email address as the sender. This sounds pretty straightforward; however, I keep on getting an exception every time I try to execute the method. I also tried this on my personal office365 account and it works perfectly, I'm only getting the issue when I'm using my company email.

**Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll**

Here's my smtp setup (We use outlook).

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, Password);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I'm thinking that I should use our own version of "smtp.live.com" if ever there is, or maybe use another port? I tried using port 25 but still the same issue.

Comment: can you try 465 for port number

Comment: @Aytekin sorry that didn't work either :(

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: @KentAbrio can you share the exception when you send to your company? the only thing I can think of that your company email not being accepted by Outlook/Hotmail servers because it might not be configured to Microsoft servers standard. there is a lot of parameters to check if your email is set correctly up, let me know to give a more formulated answer.

Comment: Why not use Outlook automatic emailing system or make an add in?

Comment: Have you tried port 465?

Comment: Are your  company's password is correct?!, you really logged in by that password you have, you said your personal email works fine

Answer (score 1):

A bit more details in terms of *personal office365 account* and *company email (outlook)* settings along with the complete error stacktrace would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However here are some insights:

---

### Sending automated email using personal Office365 account

The SMTP settings to send automated email using Microsoft 365 are as follows:

- *Server*: smtp.office365.com
- *Port*: 587
- *Encryption*: STARTTLS

---

### Sending automated email using company email account

If your organization is using either of Outlook.com/Hotmail.com/Live.com as email provider, the SMTP settings are identical:

- *Server*: smtp.office365.com
- *Port*: 587
- *Encryption*: STARTTLS

---

### Sending automated email using company email account

If your organization is using either of Outlook.com/Hotmail.com/Live.com as email provider, the SMTP settings are identical:

- *Server*: smtp.office365.com
- *Port*: 587
- *Encryption*: STARTTLS

> Reference: You can find a relevant documentations in [POP and IMAP email settings for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353)

### Sending automated email using Windows Live Hotmail SMTP Settings

If you intent to use the Windows Live Hotmail SMTP, the settings are:

- *Hotmail SMTP Server*: smtp.live.com
- *Hotmail SMTP Username*: Complete Windows Live Hotmail email address (e.g. KentAbrio@hotmail.com or KentAbrio@live.com)
- *Hotmail SMTP Password*: Your Windows Live Hotmail password
- *Hotmail SMTP Port*: 587
- *Hotmail SMTP TLS/SSL Required*: Yes

> Reference: You can find a relevant documentations in [Windows Live Hotmail SMTP Settings](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-windows-live-hotmail-smtp-settings-1170861)

---

### Sample Code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmail, "Password");
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("KentAbrio@hotmail.com", "KentAbrio@live.com", "test", "test");
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: @KentAbrio Checkout the updated answer. I have added a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line:

```
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

and add this line:

```
smtp.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
```

Also the next solution is trying removing this line only:

```
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

I am pretty much sure this works out.
Please try with different ports (25 or 587 or 465) or else with no port at all.